# Is there a way to mock a class and use regular class construction?

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

**Background:** I am still learning to use mocks and am trying to test a WordPress plugin. I would prefer to not load WordPress and simply use mocks to fake class/function where needed and only test my code's inputs and outputs.

I am trying to do the following:

```
// WP_Query IS NOT DEFINED

$mock = \Mockery::mock('WP_Query', array('have_posts' => true));

$this->assertTrue($mock->have_posts());

$q = new WP_Query();

// fails with "Call to undefined method WP_Query::have_posts()"
$this->assertTrue($q->have_posts());
```

Is the above possible with Mockery?

Answer (score 2):

When passed an array as the second argument to `Mockery::mock`, it's expecting constructor arguments, not the methods to be mocked.

Instead, you need:

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock('WP_Query');
$mock->shouldReceive('have_posts')->andReturn(true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produces the same result as described above.

Comment: On your sample you're testing an assertion on the mock and then underneath you're testing a straight instance of WP_Query. If $q is indeed an instance of that class then the method simply doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess I assumed that Mockery would actually construct it for me. So if I was testing a second object "B" which would use WP_Query, I could mock out WP_Query's definition prior to "B" using it.

Comment: You've mocked it but then you weren't using the mock, you were using a regular instance of it.

Comment: so it's just not possible to use the regular instance as I've intended